# how to find positive minimum number in array C#

Tags: c#

how can I find only positive minimum number in array C#
Im using Console.WriteLine("The minumum number is {0}", myarray.Min())

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Wish there was a search engine for stuff like that. I bet the URL would look like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+find+positive+minimum+number+in+array+C%23

Comment: `myarray.Where(t => t >= 0).Min()`?

Comment: @derape: even though the best match is this question ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Google is just too fast! :-)

Comment: for homework questions you are prob better looping through the array. 'use the microsoft supplied answer' is only a good solution in the real world :)

Answer (score 3):

Presuming an `int[]` as input:

```
int minPosNum = myarray.Where(i => i > 0).Min();
```

That throws an `InvalidOperationException` if there is no positive number. So you could use this approach using [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx) instead:

```
int minPosNum = myarray.Where(i => i > 0).DefaultIfEmpty(int.MinValue).Min();
```

here's the homework answer, use a loop:

```
int minPosNum = int.MaxValue;
foreach (int i in myarray)
    if (i > 0 && i < minPosNum)
        minPosNum = i;
```

This loop has only one issue: you don't know if there was a positive number if the result is `int.MaxValue` because that could either mean there was none or there was only an `int.MaxValue` in the array. Then you can use this clumsy approach:

```
int minPosNum = int.MaxValue;
bool positiveNumberFound = false;
foreach (int i in myarray)
{
    if (i > 0) 
    {
        positiveNumberFound = true;
        if(i < minPosNum) minPosNum = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Where` to eliminate negative numbers before `Min`:

```
myarray.Where(x => x >= 0).Min()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use just the `Min` method. There is no need to use additional methods like `Where` to filter the array. Here is an example:

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 0, -1 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 3, 1, 0, -2 };
int? min1 = arr1.Min(e => e > 0 ? e : null); // returns null
int? min2 = arr2.Min(e => e > 0 ? e : null); // returns 1
```

My solution returns `null` if there is no positive number.